# Confusion of sign in cohomology and homology pairing

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $(X,A),(Y,B)$ be two pairs of topological spaces. Denote $\times$ as external cross product on cohomology level and $E:C_\star(X,A)\otimes C_\star(Y,B)\to C_\star((X,A)\times(Y\times B))$ as Eilenberg-Zilber map and assume appropriate hypothesis(i.e. excision pairs on $A,B$ and $A\times Y, X\times B$ excision pairs) s.t. $E$ induce homology level isomorphism. Set $<-,->:H^p(X;G_1)\otimes H_p(X,G_2)\to G_1\otimes_Z G_2$ as bilinear pairing where $G_i$ are abelian groups. Whenever abelian group is omitted in homology, it is assumed to be $Z$ coefficients.

$\textbf{Q:}$ I am quite confused about the following equation's sign $(-1)^{pq}$. "$a\in H_p(X,A),b\in H_q(Y,B),u\in H^p(X,A;G_1),v\in H^q(Y,B;G_2)$, then $(-1)^{pq}<u\times v,E(a\otimes b)>=<u,a>\otimes<v,b>$." Where is $(-1)^{pq}$ coming from?

The following is my reasoning. First $\times$ is supercommutative. Hence $u\times v=(-1)^{pq}v\times u$. Now I can use $H^q(Y,B,G_2)\otimes H^p(X,A,G_1)\otimes H_p(X,A)\otimes H_q(Y,B)\to H^q(Y,B,G_2)\otimes G_1\otimes H^q(Y,B,G_2)$ where I have used obvious $<-,->$ pairing once. Now I can flip $G_1$ by $A\otimes B\cong B\otimes A$ natural. And keep contraction. This gives the equation.

However, I do not see difference between $H^q(X,A,G_1)\times H^p(Y,B,G_2)\times H_q(X,A)\times H_p(Y,B)\to G_1\otimes G_2$ by directly contracting first slot and thirs slot and contracting second slot with the fourth slot. This reasoning does not give rise to $(-1)^{pq}$.

$\textbf{Q':}$ What is the loop hole in the above reasoning? Obviously, I did not use any cohomology ring supercommutativity property.

Say $X,Y$ are smooth orientable manifolds. Essentially I should think $<-,->$ as integration of forms on manifolds. Say I am looking at compact cohomology theory. Now $\int_{U\times V}\omega_1\wedge\omega_2=\int_U\omega_1\times\int_V\omega_2$ where I assume $\omega_i$ are parametrized by standard coordinates and using canonical orientation induced on $X\times Y$ with $U,V$ identified as homology cycle to be integrated. This does give rise to $(-1)^{pq}$ somehow.

$\textbf{Q'':}$ What is the loop hole in the reasoning here?

Comment: Minor side-note while I finish reading it: \langle and \rangle are how you make inner products look not-awful on here.

Comment: For $Q)$, either $u\times v=(-1)^{pq}v\times u$, or $v\otimes a=(-1)^{qp}a\otimes v$, so everything is consistent.

Comment: @Tyrone Then why I should care about the order of contraction to produce. As far as I could see, there is difference between order of contractions and conventions adopted for evaluation by chain maps.

Comment: The contractions themselves can actually be performed at the same time, so there is no difficulty ordering them. However you need to pair homology with cohomology, so the $(-1)^{pq}$ sign comes from commuting the homological element $a$ and cohomological element $v$. Once this is done you simultaneously pair $(u,a)$ and $(v,b)$ to get an element in $G_1\otimes G_2$. Since the coefficents are concentrated in degree $0$ there are no more signs to worry about.

Comment: @Tyrone Maybe the dumb question is why do I need such a sign for contraction? Is this intended to make contraction as chain map between $H^\star\otimes H_\star\to Z$ where $Z$ is the complex concentrated at $0$ position?

Comment: @Tyrone This is different from standard pairing of dual and original space which does not involve chain map definition or this is generalization of standard pairing. So standard pairing should be treated as complex concentrated at degree $0$. Then I should see this very contraction of complexes and its dual generalizes the standard contraction.

Comment: No sign arises from any *contraction*. You have $(H^p(X)\otimes H^q(X))\otimes (H_p(X)\otimes H_q(X))=H^p(X)\otimes (H^q(X)\otimes H_p(X))\otimes H_q(X)\xrightarrow{1\otimes(-1)^{pq}\otimes 1}H^p(X)\otimes (H_p(X)\otimes H^q(X))\otimes H_q(X)=(H^p(X)\otimes H_p(X))\otimes (H^q(X)\otimes H_q(X))\xrightarrow{contr.\otimes contr.}G_1\otimes G_2\xrightarrow{pair}G_3$

Comment: @Tyrone I see. So by contraction, you mean slant product.

Comment: By contraction I mean $H^p(X)\otimes H_p(X)\rightarrow G_1\otimes G_2$. I'm sorry if my notation is a bit different from yours, but hopefully you see what I am trying to convey. The point is that you cannot "directly contract the first and third slots". You must first commute either the second and third, or the first and second. This gives you a sign change either way.

Comment: @Tyrone I see. Thanks.